# Moving Script to Function and New Columns not retaining values properly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am new and don't know what I'm doing. I searched Stack Overflow and couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

What I want to do is sort a data frame based on the values in a column, then create a new column, then assign a rank (1 through 4 in this case) based on the sorted list. Then do it again based on a values in a new column.

For example:
    dfteams = dfteams.sort_values(['Wins'], ascending=[False])
        dfteams['Win_rnk'] = range(1, len(dfteams) + 1)

In my data frame (assigned the name “dfteams”) I’ve sorted the entire DF by the “Wins” column. I then created a new column named “Win_rnk” and assigned each row a ranking from 1 to 4 (since that’s how many rows I have in my data frame).

That works. And if I do it again based on a new stat, it works perfectly fine as well.

However, if I take the same code and drop it into a function, all the new columns end up with identical values (ranked based on the last column I sorted by).  And I have no idea why it works as part of the script directly, but not when executed via a function.

Header = Team, Wins, Losses, Points

Team1, 7, 1, 560

Team2, 6, 2, 595

Team3, 5, 3, 403

Team4, 4, 4, 460

I want to add the Win_rnk column (with the above example code):
Header = Team, Wins, Losses, Points, Win_rnk

Team1, 7, 1, 560, 1

Team2, 6, 2, 595, 2

Team3, 5, 3, 403, 3

Team4, 4, 4, 460, 4

I then want to add the Points_rnk column (same code as the example but calling the dfteams['Points'] to sort by:

Header = Team, Wins, Losses, Points, Win_rnk, Points_rnk

Team2, 6, 2, 595, 2, 1

Team1, 7, 1, 560, 1, 2

Team4, 4, 4, 460, 4, 3

Team3, 5, 3, 403, 3, 4

In my script, that works. I want to move the code to a function, but when I do I end up having both of the new columns with the same values.

def ranking_stats(dfteams):
    dfteams = dfteams.sort_values(['Wins'], ascending=[False])
    dfteams['Win_rnk'] = range(1, len(dfteams) + 1)

```
dfteams = dfteams.sort_values(['Points'], ascending=[False])
dfteams['Points_rnk'] = range(1, len(dfteams) + 1)
```

When I call the function rather than running it directly in a script it gives me this:

Header = Team, Wins, Losses, Points, Win_rnk, Points_rnk

Team2, 6, 2, 595, 1, 1

Team1, 7, 1, 560, 2, 2

Team4, 4, 4, 460, 3, 3

Team3, 5, 3, 403, 4, 4

Note that now the Win_rnk column is returned with the same values as Points_rnk.  Which isn't what I am trying to do.

There is probably something basic that I don't understand since I'm completely new to programming, but after searching for an answer and not being able to locate one, I'm hoping someone can tell me what it is I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make function like this,

```
def ranking_stats(dfteams): 
    dfteams = dfteams.sort_values(['Wins'], ascending=[False])
    dfteams['Win_rnk'] = range(1, len(dfteams) + 1)
    dfteams = dfteams.sort_values(['Points'], ascending=[False])
    dfteams['Points_rnk'] = range(1, len(dfteams) + 1)
    return dfteams
```

Input Dataframe -> dfteams,

```
      Team   Wins   Losses  Points
0     Team1   7       1      560
1     Team2   6       2      595
2     Team3   5       3      403
3     Team4   4       4      460
```

Now, call `ranking_stats()` like this,

```
dfteams = ranking_stats(dfteams)
dfteams
```

Output:

```
Team    Wins    Losses  Points  Win_rnk Points_rnk
1   Team2   6         2      595      2         1
0   Team1   7         1      560      1         2
3   Team4   4         4      460      4         3
2   Team3   5         3      403      3         4
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't tell what you did differently, but it's working now.

Comment: @mgadfly please give an up-vote to this answer so other can get advantage from this answer.

Comment: @mgadfly also **accept** this answer if this worked well for you.

Comment: It let me accept, but my reputation will not allow me to upvote it.  I'm still too new.